# How to create dynamic CheckBoxes inside a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a `GridView` that displays the `Approvers` list. As shown in below image. I need to show CheckBoxes, if there are multiple `Approvers` in a column. Is it possible? If yes then how can I achieve it?

[image]

E.g The `Approvers` section has multiple *Approver Names* in the first row, for which I should show CheckBoxes.

The data displayed in the grid is available in a `DataTable` and the multiple `Approvers` are part of a single row hence I can't use `TemplateField` and display CheckBoxes.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate more on how you are generating the GridView.

Comment: @VDWWD The grid is bind to DataTable which has all the information in exact same format. I have only done grouping for Business Unit column. The approver names are ; seperated.

Comment: where is your gridview code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution. I could achieve this in method `OnRowDataBound()`. Not sure if this is the best way.

```
protected void grdApproverDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string ApproverName  = ((Label)e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("lblANgrd")).Text;

                string[] approvers = ApproverName.Split(';');
                if (approvers.Count() > 1)
                {
                    ((Label)e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("lblANgrd")).Text = "";

                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (var item in approvers)
                    {
                        CheckBox ckb = new CheckBox();
                        ckb.Text = item;
                        ckb.ID = i.ToString();
                        ckb.ID = "approvernamesdynamic_"+i.ToString();
                        ckb.Checked = true;
                        e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(ckb);
                        i++;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```